# How To Replace Words To Asterisk In Notepad++

Tags: regex

I have thousands of URLS formatting like

```
http://www.domain1.com
http://www.domain2.co.uk
http://www.domain3.org
etc etc
```

I want to make them to:

```
http://www.********.com
http://www.*******.co.uk
http://www.*****.org
```

I have to replace those words with asterisk sign before the end of the domain extension in Notepad++, Is it possible to do so?

Comment: Show what you have already tried, and try to find edge cases in your list (domains with more than one word if any for example: `www.toto.tutu.com`). Note that this can be more easily solved with a programming language.

Comment: If the domain names do not contain a dot, it is easy. Do you have URLs like `http://my.domain.org` --> `http://**.******.org`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes it is possible.

in the replace form (ctr + h) enabled regular expression then write `[.](.)*[.]` in the find what textbox and write .***. in the Replace with textbox.

> find what: `[.](.)*[.]`
>   Replace with: `.***.`

Comment: It does not work because the number of `*` is hardcoded in this S&R. The requirement is that the number of `*` should equal the number of characters in the word replaced - at least the examples say so.

Answer (score 0):

My solution will replace all domain name with a fixed number of stars

- type any numer of stars somewhere, then copy it to clipboard. Delete these stars
- Move your cursor to your first line
- Click on record macro
- Press right arrow 4 times with shift key down
- Press right arrow once while pressing CTRL+Shift
- Press CONTROL+V (domain name is replaced by stars)
- Press HOME key then key down
- Click strop record button

Then press play macro in loop till the end of file